# How to view tcp connection errors in apache/ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, tcp

I am load testing a ubuntu/apache2 server and after 500 concurrent connections my load testing software is telling me there are connection errors.

The errors are not showing up in apache error log.

Is there another way to see what kind of errors these are and get some visibility?
tcp connection reset? too many connections?

Comment: Is this an error performing a connection or an error during a established connection?

Comment: I am not sure that's why i'd like to do some investigating. How would you approach the situation?

Answer (score 2):

You probably will never see connection errors creating a new connection (since they dont reach apache), but connection errors during established connections should come through your error log typically as a 'connection reset by peer' or 'connection timed out' type of messages.

This is probably due to the listen backlog in apache. If all the workers/child processes are handling all the connections, the listen backlog will fill up and the client probably is intolerant to waiting in the listen queue and closes the connection.

You'll never get a log message for this as apache never accepts that connection.

Comment: Check MaxClient and ServerLimit settings in your apache.conf.